# How to check if a line in a file exceeds a number of characters

Tags: file, batch-file, lines

I am wondering if there is an easy way to check for files in a directory that contain a line that exceeds a certain number of characters. For example, I have a directory with 10000 files and I would like to see which files have at least one line that has over 1000 characters. Is it possible to check this via a batch script? Thank you.

This is for Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit, Service Pack 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest and fastest way would be to use the `grep` [binary](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) from GnuWin32.  I believe this syntax would work:

```
grep -Pl ".{1000}" *
```

Which will perform a perl-syntax regular expression search in `*` for any line containing 1000 characters, and output the filename if a match is found.

It would definitely be possible to accomplish what you are asking with a pure batch script, but a `for` loop looping through 10,000 files with who-knows-how-many lines each, would take forever and a day.

---

OK Prof. Pickle, here's your batch file.  I went with using [variable substring extraction](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for speed.  Also, if a line with 1000 characters is encountered, immediately move to the next file.  I still reckon `grep` will be faster and simpler.  `o°/`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
    call :look "%%a"
)

goto :EOF

:look
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%~1") do (
    set "line=%%I"
    if "!line:~999,1!" neq "" echo %~1 && exit /b
)
```

Comment: Surely its not too much to ask to get an all batch solution as well. Anyway, +1 for trying to make a batch file fast.

Comment: @ProfPickle - There you go.

Comment: really nice batch idea for this question, +1

Answer (score 2):

Pure batch:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=1-2delims=:" %%i in ('"cmd /c type "%%~a" ^&echo(|findstr /no ^^"') do (
    set "pos1=!pos0!"&set "line1=!line0!"
    set "pos0=%%j"&set "line0=%%i"
    set /a length=!pos0!-!pos1!-2
    if !length! gtr 1000 echo line: !line1! length: !length! in file: %%~a
))
```

Change *.txt to your desired search pattern.

Edit: minor improvement (`^^`).

Comment: +1, That should work, but there are 2 limitations: File size must be less than 2 gigabytes, and lines must use Windows style, (ending with CR/LF), not Unix style (ending with LF). Unix style files will have line length off by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much faster solution with a temp file:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
 <"%%~a">"%tempfile%" more
 echo(>>"%tempfile%"
 for /f "tokens=1-2delims=:" %%i in ('^"^< "%tempfile%" findstr /no "^" ^"') do (
    set "pos1=!pos0!"&set "line1=!line0!"
    set "pos0=%%j"&set "line0=%%i"
    set /a length=!pos0!-!pos1!-2
    if !length! gtr 0 echo line: !line1! length: !length! in file: %%~a
))
del "%tempfile%" >nul 2>&1
```

Edit: improved escaping for XP.